# group_by with Impala Ibis

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, cloudera, impala

I have an Impala table that I'd like to query using Ibis. The table looks like the following:

```
   id  | timestamp
-------------------
 A     | 5
 A     | 7
 A     | 3
 B     | 9
 B     | 5
```

I'd like to `group_by` this table according to unique combinations of `id` and `timestamp range`. The grouping operation should ultimately produce a single `grouped` object that I can then apply aggregations on. For example:

group1 conditions: `id == A; 4 < timestamp < 11`
group2 conditions: `id == A; 1 < timestamp < 6`
group3 conditions: `id == B; 4 < timestamp < 7`

yielding a `grouped` object with the following groups:

group1:

```
   id  | timestamp
-------------------
 A     | 5
 A     | 7
```

group2:

```
   id  | timestamp
-------------------
 A     | 5
 A     | 3
```

group3:

```
   id  | timestamp
-------------------
 B     | 5
```

Once I have the groups I'll perform various aggregations to get my final results. If anybody could help me figure this group_by out it would be greatly appreciated, even a regular pandas expression would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

So here is an example for `groupby` (no underscore):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id":["a","b","a","b","c","c"], "timestamp":[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
```

create a grouper column for your `timestamp`.

```
df["my interval"] = (df["timestamp"] > 3 )&  (df["timestamp"] <5)
"you need some _data_ columns, i.e. those which you do not use for grouping"
df["dummy"] = 1 
df.groupby(["id", "my interval"]).agg("count")["dummy"]
```

Or you can use both:

```
df["something that I need"] = df["my interval"] & (df["id"] == "b")
df.groupby(["something that I need"]).agg("count")["dummy"]
```

you might also want to apply integer division to generate time intervals:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id":["a","b","a","b","c","c"], "timestamp":[1,2,13,14,25,26], "sales": [0,4,2,3,6,7]})
epoch = 10
df["my interval"] = epoch* (df["timestamp"] // epoch)
df.groupby(["my interval"]).agg(sum)["sales"]
```

### EDIT:

your example:

```
import pandas as pd
A = "A"
B = "B"
df = pd.DataFrame({"id":[A,A,A,B,B], "timestamp":[5,7,3,9,5]})
df["dummy"] = 1
```

Solution:

```
grouper = (df["id"] == A) & (4 < df["timestamp"] ) & ( df["timestamp"] < 11)
df.groupby( grouper ).agg(sum)["dummy"]
```

or better:

```
df[grouper]["dummy"].sum()
```

Comment: Hi Dima, thanks for your answer. The challenge I'm facing is creating multiple, sometimes overlapping time bins that only apply to specific `id`s. If you try to produce the groups from my example you'll see what I mean. As a side-note, pandas has a handy convenience function for grouping on binned values called `pd.cut`.

Comment: if you have overlapping intervals, you will need several `groupby` operations, or more efficiently you can use logical indexing. See last edit

Comment: As I mentioned, the problem is to produce all groups with a single `groupby`. Again, try to solve the complete example and you will appreciate the challenge.

Comment: Consider king Salomon grouping an infant by its mother, and you will realize that the challenge is indeed fundamental. If you want to split a finite set into a finite number of subsets, you cannot include one element of an initial subset in several groups

Comment: Groupby operates on labels, that is you give each element a label which maps it to a subset. You may not have two labels that map one element to several subsets.

Comment: if you really believe it is the only way, you will need to cut your infants into halves, i.e. devise a scheme to duplicate your rows.

Comment: and please note that `pd.cut` also does return non-overlapping intervals. So it is equivalent in your case to integer division.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the luxury of duplicating rows, my actual data-set is in an Impala table distributed on a cluster and potentially multiple TB in size. Also, I wasn't implying that `pd.cut` could produce overlapping sets, just that  it was an elegant way to group according to bin. Anyway, thanks for your effort.

Comment: is my solution _a solution_ to your problem? if yes, please upvote.

Comment: Sorry, your solution is in no way a solution to my problem.